# Copy, paste to new map & remove line break

Tags: excel, vba, replace, copy, paste

The task is: Copy values in a specific range, open a new excel workbook, paste those values and remove all line breaks in column B in the new workbook. Currently I struggle hard with managing this in VBA.

```
Sub RemoveBreaks()
Dim Text As String

Range("A1:C3").Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Text = Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Replace(Str(10), "")
End Sub
```

For some crazy reason I currently do not understand this code actually works on 1 PC but does not do anything on a different PC. Any idea why or how can i fix this?

When I add:

```
Range("B:B") = Text
```

I only get the value "true" in column B in the new workbook sheet.

Thank you very much for your help, much appriciated!
Best regards

Comment: "I only get the value "true" in column B in the new workbook sheet" - that's because `Range.Replace` returns a **Boolean**, as noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace). Normally you would call `Range.Replace` by itself and discard this result, i.e. not assign it to a variable (see the code snippet in the docs).

Comment: Hmm the problem is that when I try to use range. replace (e.g.: Range("B1:B2").Replace(Str(10), "") I get a compilation error (wrong syntax)

Comment: Remove the parentheses after `Replace`.

Comment: Nice, you're a god, thank you very much :) For anyone else with the same issue try vbNewLine instead of Str(10). This finally did the trick: Range("H2:H5").Replace vbNewLine, ""

Comment: ^ Feel free to post this as an answer, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
Text = Sheets(1).Range("B:B").Replace(Str(10), "")
```

And use:

```
Range("B:B").Replace vbNewLine, ""
```

instead. Many thanks to BigBen for the help!